# For na linguagem C

Tags: c, for, sintaxe

Estudei o artifício iterativo `for` e achava que o mesmo se aplicava igual ao seguinte exemplo:

```
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){Código}
```

Porém, ao estudar a parte de ponteiro com vetores, me deparei com o seguinte exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
      int vet[7]={0};
      int i;

      for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        printf("%d ",*(vet+i)); //Mostrando todos os valores do vetor
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("%i \n\n",vet); //Mostrando o endereco de memoria do primeiro indice do vetor

      for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        printf("%i ",(vet+i)); //Mostrando todos os endereco de memoria do vetor
        printf("\n\n");

      *(vet+5)=1024; //Alterando o indice seis para 1024
      for(i=0;i<7;i++)
         printf("%d ",*(vet+i)); //Exibindo todos os indices do vetor
         
      getchar();
      }
```

Por que o autor desse código não usou as chaves e o artifício de iteração funcionou? No meu compilador (CodeBlocks), se botar as chaves o programa não retorna igual ao anterior.

Comment: Na realidade sua indentação está errada. Apenas o primeiro `printf` que se segue ao `for` é que é executado no loop. Os demais printf são executados **após** o término do loop. Você utilize o bloco `{}` quando quer executar mais de um comando dentro do loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse código é mal escrito e passa uma ideia errada do que ele faz. Escrito de uma forma melhor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int vet[7] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) printf("%d ", vet[i]); //Mostrando todos os valores do vetor
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("%d\n\n", vet); //Mostrando o endereco de memoria do primeiro indice do vetor
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) printf("%d ", (vet + i)); //Mostrando todos os endereco de memoria do vetor
    printf("\n\n");
    vet[5] = 1024; //Alterando o indice seis para 1024
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) printf("%d ", vet[i]); //Exibindo todos os indices do vetor
    getchar();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Example.c).

Dá para escrever de outras formas mas agora fica mais claro e legível.

Quer usar chaves? Ok, use e deixando mais próximo do original, sem motivos. Quando não há chaves e quer por só pode conter uma linha de comando dentro dela, se colocar mais linhas está mudando a semântica do código. Indentação não define o que é um bloco de comandos, só a chave cria um bloco, se não tinha chave, então não tinha bloco, só uma linha pertence ao comando `for`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int vet[7] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(vet + i)); //Mostrando todos os valores do vetor
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("%i \n\n", vet); //Mostrando o endereco de memoria do primeiro indice do vetor
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%d ", (vet + i)); //Mostrando todos os endereco de memoria do vetor
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    *(vet + 5) = 1024; //Alterando o indice seis para 1024
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(vet + i)); //Exibindo todos os indices do vetor
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Lição a ser aprendida: não use como exemplo código que você não entende e dado por pessoas que não se preocupam em escrever um código legível e moderno.

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado @Manieiro! Obrigado pelas dicas, irão me ajudar muito na construção da minha jornada aprendendo essa linguagem de programação.